# Wix Directory Problems

Tags: installation, wix, heat

I have two questions about the directories with using fragments in Windows Installer XML.

I got this fragment file from the heat.exe:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Name="Test" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="InstallationFiles">
            <Component Id="cmp071F7F8F6B6027C8D2841272FE526A2B" Directory="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Guid="{CCCB70AC-29F5-4DAA-B03E-1A2266649AB6}">
                <File Id="fil63087E96FFB31F9E39B642CE8914F48B" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\dmedv.jpg" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpAE6CBEDA75641CF25BA9996AEB74A0DE" Directory="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Guid="{F5DABCAB-95D1-4197-A49F-E5F052A8E7EF}">
                <File Id="filD27F2F6B26F5C14563865FE6C2AD5D50" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Files.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp25C5EADB5C0A9E779D20EC7B77BD42B0" Directory="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Guid="{E301B04A-6EA5-496B-A58A-8898110BE57C}">
                <File Id="fil7C91C48D9AA0F2FE0EB37A21F108037F" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\readme.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpD387AB4B40EDF14BF271ADDA7B71D2B7" Directory="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Guid="{6AF61DF4-32D0-4E7C-95B8-1DB9E7409029}">
                <File Id="fil966691BA382AFC9343430FE162643432" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\readme1.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpB86212407C1BEA12838C8C7B20495E9F" Directory="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" Guid="{921E971E-E224-464C-9FBC-FBC5F78B3E5B}">
                <File Id="fil61CD8EF43EA29DF58454E9A19F8C1EF9" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\readme2.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpE4143B48FF854AE84F6054D4636FDE81" Directory="dir0ADF7E89B935DD39670130B4DC1D670E" Guid="{6F248718-93DD-4850-A18E-BD7079F738D5}">
                <File Id="fil03847B355B6AADE5E4E04D143C92BC67" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Test2\dmedv2.jpg" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir0ADF7E89B935DD39670130B4DC1D670E" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir08A07F5561FBEB6B9772467C730F6445">
            <Directory Id="dir0ADF7E89B935DD39670130B4DC1D670E" Name="Test2" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and I have this wix installer file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>

<?define ProductVersion="1.0.0.0"?>
<?define ProductName="DMServices Installer"?>
<?define Manufacturer="DM EDV- und Bürosysteme GmbH"?>

<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'  xmlns:iis='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension'>
  <Product Name="$(var.ProductName)" Id='BB7FBBE4-0A25-4cc7-A39C-AC916B665220' UpgradeCode='8A5311DE-A125-418f-B0E1-5A30B9C667BD'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)">

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer'
      Description="DMService Installer Setup"
      Manufacturer='DM EDV- und Bürosysteme GmbH'
      InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="the man" />

    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35"/>
    <Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5.'>
      <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK35)]]>
    </Condition>

   <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder'>
        <Directory Id='DM' Name='DM EDV'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='DMServices'>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
   </Directory>

<Feature Id='InstallationFiles' Title='InstallationFiles' Level='1'>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id='InstallationFiles' />
    </Feature>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

So far.

Now when i generate this files to wixobj, the compiler shows errors because the files can't be found. The files are in a directory called "Test". And in the file it's named SourceDir.

For a lil workaround i can copy the test directory and call it SourceDir ;-). So my Setup will be created.

1. How can I do it without a second directory?

   - **EDIT: Problem is done**.

Now i install my package. But whatever i do, the files will be installed to C:\Test.

But I want it to be installed in my Program Files Directory.

In many examples i can do it, like in the file, but i have to know the guids. 
But we do wix for getting all files from one directory, without to put our hands on.

1. So how to install the files into the program files directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a closer look at `-dr` switch of `heat.exe`. You can put the necessary directory reference there. So, define your directory structure in the main file as you do now, and provide correct directory ID to `heat.exe`.

UPDATE:

Ok, the following works for me. The main directory structure:

```
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="My folder">
        <Directory Id="WebsiteFolder" Name="Website">
        ...
        </Directory>
     </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

The Feature references the ComponentGroup:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="!(loc.ProductFeature.Title)" Level="100">
     ...
     <ComponentGroupRef Id="WebsiteFolderComponentGroup"/>
     ...
  </Feature>
```

The heat.exe generates the following fragment:

```
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="WebsiteFolder">
            <Component Id="cmp1" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                <File Id="fil1" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\Default.aspx" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp2" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                <File Id="fil2" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\default.css" />
            </Component>
            <Directory Id="dir1" Name="App_Browsers">
                <Component Id="cmp3" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                    <File Id="fil3" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\App_Browsers\Form.browser" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="App_Config" Name="App_Config">
                <Component Id="cmp4" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                    <File Id="fil4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="bin" Name="bin">
                <Component Id="cmp5" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                    <File Id="fil5" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\bin\MySystem.Web.UI.dll" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp6" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
                    <File Id="fil6" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.WebsiteFolderSource)\bin\Another.dll" />
                </Component>
              ...
            </Directory>
        ...
        </Directory>

...

        <ComponentGroup Id="WebsiteFolderComponentGroup">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp1" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp2" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp3" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp4" />
            ...
        </ComponentGroup>
```

And finally, the heat command which generates necessary output looks like this (Nant sample):

```
  <exec program="heat.exe" verbose="true" basedir="${paths.source}">
     <arg line='dir "${paths.dist.website}"'/><!-- Notice the quotes inside the attributes -->
     <arg line='-srd'/>
     <arg line='-dr WebsiteFolder'/>
     <arg line='-cg WebsiteFolderComponentGroup'/>
     <arg line='-out "${paths.harvest}\website.wxs"'/>
     <arg line='-ke -sfrag -scom -sreg -gg'/>
     <arg line='-var var.WebsiteFolderSource'/>
  </exec>
```

These snippets contain enough information to understand how it all works. Play with heat.exe switches to find out the combination you need. Good luck!

Comment: Now i have build the setup with the Directory Choosing. But the same. The Files will be installed to C:\Test. 

I have to tell the wix Setup file:

`<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder'>
        <Directory Id='DM' Name='DM EDV'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='DMServices'>
           INSTALL FEATURE HERE

          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
   </Directory>`

Comment: Investigate the first lesson of well-known tutorial: http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson1.php and download the ready-made sample. It should answer your questions about directory structures

Comment: When i know all component Guids and Names, then i can write it into the directory tree. But i got a segment with all the files, which will be read in the Feature Group (over ComponentGroupRef Id). How i install this Group into the directories?

Comment: I'll try to drop you a sample today or tomorrow

Comment: This is the best piece of WIX documentation I ever found in the intertubes. Thank you very much for sharin.

Comment: I did it exactly as shown above but when building i got some ICE64 errors. Any idea what i did wrong? For some code see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413247/wix-ice-64-error-link-external-componentgroups

Comment: I am building from CLI.  Where `var.WebsiteFolderSource` came from I couldn't figure out.   But if I instead used `wix.WebsiteFolderSource` and then passed `-dWebsiteFolderSource=<some\path\here>` to light.exe it worked great!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case people like me still looking for clarification: The `<DirectoryRef Id="WebsiteFolder">` in the heat fragment is important, it is the reference to where the fragment files should be installed. If you have multiple fragments and want to place it in different locations, the DirectoryRef is the key.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail?